# Laplace Transform of $\frac{e^{\frac{-a^2}{4t}}}{\sqrt{\pi t}}$.

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I would like the Laplace Transform of $$\frac{e^{\frac{-a^2}{4t}}}{\sqrt{\pi t}}.$$

Using the definition of a Laplace transform I need to evaluate the integral $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-a^2}{4u^2}-su^2\right)du$$

This is where I'm stuck. I've been given that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-c^2}{x^2}-c^2x^2\right)dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2|c|}e^{-2c^2}$$but I don't know what value of c to choose. Any help?

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{a^2}{4 t}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi  t}}\right](s)=\fbox{$\frac{e^{-\sqrt{s} | a| }}{\sqrt{s}}\text{ if }\Re(s)>0\land a\neq 0$}$$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: Mathematica told me.

Comment: Okay, good to know the answer I suppose, but any ideas how to do it by hand using the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $s>0$ and $a\ne0.$ In order to have
$$\frac{-a^2}{4u^2}=\frac{-c^2}{x^2}\quad\text{and}\quad su^2=c^2x^2,$$
choose
$$c=\sqrt{\frac{|a|\sqrt s}2}\quad\text{and}\quad x=u\frac{\sqrt s}c.$$
Using the identity you have been given, i.e.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-c^2}{x^2}-c^2x^2\right)dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2|c|}e^{-2c^2},$$
you get:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-a^2}{4u^2}-su^2\right)du=\frac1{\sqrt s}e^{-|a|\sqrt s}.$$
By uniqueness of the analytic continuation, $\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{\exp \left(-\frac{a^2}{4 t}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi  t}}\right](s)=\frac1{\sqrt s}e^{-|a|\sqrt s}$ holds not only for every real number $s>0$ but for every complex number $s$ such that $\Re(s)>0.$

Answer (score 2):

First let $t=su^2$ which gives that

$$
I = \int_0^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{4u^2}-su^2\right) du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}} \int_0^{\infty} \exp\left(\frac{sa^2}{4t}-t \right) \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}}
$$

This is a form of a [Bessel function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E10) which gives

$$
 \int_0^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{sa^2}{4t}-t \right) \frac{dt}{t^{1/2}} = \sqrt{2a\sqrt{s}}K_{1/2}(a\sqrt{s})
$$

such that we have

$$
I = \frac{\sqrt{a\sqrt{s}}}{\sqrt{2s}}K_{1/2}(a\sqrt{s})
$$

Since

$$K_{1/2}(a\sqrt{s}) = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-a\sqrt{s}}}{\sqrt{a\sqrt{s}}}
$$

we may simplify to obtain

$$
I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{-a\sqrt{s}}}{\sqrt{2s}}
$$

which in the end gives that the Laplace transform is

$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{a^2}{4u^2}-su^2\right) du =  \frac{e^{-a\sqrt{s}}}{\sqrt{s}}
$$

as mentioned in the hint. I've assumed $a>0$ which is possible to extend to negative values as well, which then gives the absolute value.